# Upload image using UIImagePickerController to dragonfly on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, ruby, uiimagepickercontroller, dragonfly-gem

I have a app for iOS and I have the user pick a image with a UIImagePickerController.  How can I upload that image to my rails app using dragonfly.  I think I would use multipart-image-data but I don't know how I would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do it would be to hand off the "bag of bits" (data of the image) to [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ) to upload it your rails application.

*EDIT* To answer your question about how to handle the upload, you could do something like this. Remember to set the name used in AFNetworking is the same as the params key

```
def uploadFile
    post = DataFile.save(params[:upload])
    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
end
```

Comment: In the rails app how would I use this data